# Rake doesn't work with latest Compass? "uninitialized constant Sass::Script (NameError)"

Tags: rake, compass-sass, octopress, susy-compass

I've been playing with Octopress for few days and today wanted to try latest [Susy](http://susy.oddbird.net) v. 2.1.2 which requires Compass v. 1.0 (1.0.0.alpha.19 atm) which requires Sass v. 3.3 , as far as I know… Beside that, according to the [Susy changelog](http://susydocs.oddbird.net/en/latest/changelog/#apr-28-2014), Susy is registered with Compass 1.0 automatically.

So I modified my Gemfile:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"

group :development do
  gem 'rake', '~> 10.0'
  gem 'jekyll', '~> 0.12'
  gem 'rdiscount', '~> 2.0.7'
  gem 'pygments.rb', '~> 0.3.4'
  gem 'RedCloth', '~> 4.2.9'
  gem 'haml', '~> 3.1.7'
  gem 'compass', '1.0.0.alpha.19'
  gem 'sass', '~> 3.3'
  gem 'sass-globbing', '~> 1.0.0'
  gem 'rubypants', '~> 0.2.0'
  gem 'rb-fsevent', '~> 0.9'
  gem 'stringex', '~> 1.4.0'
  gem 'liquid', '~> 2.3.0'
  gem 'directory_watcher', '1.4.1'
end

gem 'sinatra', '~> 1.4.2'
```

So I did `bundle install`. But it seems `rake generate` neither `rake preview` don't like new Compass at all. Gettin plenty of these:

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-core-
    1.0.0.alpha.19/lib/compass/core/sass_extensions.rb:2:in `<top 
    (required)>': uninitialized constant Sass::Script (NameError)
```

Compass alone working without any problem. Though, I'm pretty new to Rake, Compass, Octopress so am I missing something?